# Why isnt my grid responsive on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have created this grid which works very well in browser with various width - boxes are moving nicely to next line and always keeping their sizes. On mobile however, everything is just scaled to be shown smaller with way too many boxes on each line.

Can can I get the mobile view to behave like the browser? Thanks!

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">1</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">2</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">3</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">4</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">5</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">6</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">7</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">8</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">9</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">10</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">11</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">12</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">13</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">14</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">15</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">16</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">17</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">18</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">19</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">20</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">21</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">22</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">23</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="dato">24</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

```
.box {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 149px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 0;
    border-radius:5px;
    height: 149px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#container {
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.text {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
.first {
    height: 190px;
}
.dato {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    font-size: 350%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e4ds38dr/

Answer (score 4):

Logically adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the head will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

it would appear to me by looking at your project that the best way to represent a grid structure would be with bootstrap.If bootstrap is used you can then change

```html
<div id="container"> with <div class="container-fluid">
```

also editing the

```html
<meta name= "viewport"...
```

tag in the head section can help for scaling but i have to find the exact syntax (sorry leaving work)